# Python, Bokeh, "oops! something went wrong" when mapping

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, bokeh

I'm working my way through the Bokeh user guide and am getting stuck on the [Mapping Geo Data section](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.12.14/docs/user_guide/geo.html).

I've pretty much copy and pasted the code, but for some reason keep getting the following:

[image]

The code as follows:

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.models import (
  GMapPlot, GMapOptions, ColumnDataSource, Circle, Range1d, PanTool, WheelZoomTool, BoxSelectTool
)

map_options = GMapOptions(lat=30.29, lng=-97.73, map_type="roadmap", zoom=11)

plot = GMapPlot(x_range=Range1d(), y_range=Range1d(), map_options=map_options)
plot.title.text = "Austin"

# For GMaps to function, Google requires you obtain and enable an API key:
#
#     https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key
#
# Replace the value below with your personal API key:
plot.api_key = "GOOGLE_API_KEY"

source = ColumnDataSource(
    data=dict(
        lat=[30.29, 30.20, 30.29],
        lon=[-97.70, -97.74, -97.78],
    )
)

circle = Circle(x="lon", y="lat", size=15, fill_color="blue", fill_alpha=0.8, line_color=None)
plot.add_glyph(source, circle)

plot.add_tools(PanTool(), WheelZoomTool(), BoxSelectTool())
output_file("gmap_plot.html")
show(plot)
```

I read that sometimes this happens because the API key is not correct - or even entered - mine is definitely correct so I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

Enabled Google APIs: 
[image]

Comment: "The documentation on this page refers to a PREVIOUS VERSION." Could that be the problem? It is also unclear, which code you mean as there are several code snippets on this page.

Comment: Sorry, I have just added the code to the question. The previous version aligns with the version of Bokeh I have installed.

Comment: This is not a Bokeh issue, the error message above is generated from Google. Either the key is invalid, or perhaps the Maps API is disabled to for the account associated with the key. Running the exact code above with my API generates a working map plot.

Comment: Hmm I have the `Maps JavaScript API` - see question. I don't use Google APIs that much

Answer (score 2):

This is almost definitively an issue with gmaps' API key. It would be useful to follow the error message's advice and check the javascript console for errors. You would know immediately then what the problem is.

Comment: Yes, it is `InvalidKeyMapError`. I have generated a brand new key for this project which is entered correctly. But no luck, hence taking to stack.

Comment: Have you enabled the Maps API in the Google console? Their UI is way overcomplicated.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the code snippets from the docs working, for any version from 0.12.14-0.12.16... Anyway. I got the below working:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
os.chdir(r'PATH')
file = 'FILE_NAME.csv' 
df = pd.read_csv(file, skipinitialspace=True) 

group = df[["ColA", "ColB", "ColC", "ColD"]]
my_source = ColumnDataSource(group)
#my_source.column_names

from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, gmap
from bokeh.models import GMapOptions, ColumnDataSource

import numpy as np 
lat_lims = df.Latitude
#lat_lims
lon_lims = df.Longitude
#lon_lims

map_options = GMapOptions(lat=np.mean(lat_lims), lng=np.mean(lon_lims), zoom=6)

p = gmap(MY_API_KEY, map_options)
p.circle("Longitude",
         "Latitude",
         source=my_source, 
         size=5)

show(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. There are at least 15 API for google MAP.

This issue can be resolved by activating

Maps JavaScript API
Google